# Можно ли узнать количество добавлений песни в ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

мне нужно узнать количество добавлений песни в ВК. Я знаю, что через VK API это сделать нельзя.
Можно ли это как-то сделать? Если можно то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, так как эта информация не предоставляется в открытом доступе никоим образом.